# can i add a number to range of elements in numper array without loops c++

Tags: c++

I want to add a certain constant value to range of elements in an array without iterating over them , can i do that ?

Example:

```
int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
add_certain_val(arr, 0, 4, 2);
// now arr == {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

Comment: It's not possible without iterating over them

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? And yes, something, somewhere has to iterate over them.

Comment: You can cheat and use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).  There is still a loop but it is hidden.

Comment: So you mean you'll always change the last value of that array? You can access it via `arr[4]`, without need of iteration.

Comment: As @NathanOliver states, it can be done via `std::transform` ([Live Example](http://ideone.com/CVkO3i)) but at some point iteration is occurring.

Comment: i think about making a pointer that point to sevral elements . can it be done or not ?

Comment: There is a 1:1 relationship between a pointer and its target.  One pointer can't point to many objects *simultaneously*.

Comment: Note:  some high level languages or applications have the capability of adding a scalar to a vector (math term) or performing other operations with a math vector.  The C++ language does not provide this functionality (see my answer below).

Comment: You could have a look at [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray), but internally , it will also use a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the addition without a loop by specifying each element individually:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
array[0] += 2;
array[1] += 2;
array[2] += 2;
array[3] += 2;
array[4] += 2;
```

We're talking *semantics* about whether or not this is iterating.

However, no pointers or iterators were used in this example.

There are no high level functions that add a scalar to a vector (array).  You may be able to find a library that has those operations.

Some processors may have instructions that can add a scalar value to an array, but the C++ language doesn't have that facility.